# Activate cell does not work on onEdit (but it does on OnOpen)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have this very trivial code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('DaSheet');

var lastWeightRow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(lastWeightRow+1,1).activate();   //Move the cursor/scroll

var normalStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(10).setBold(false).build();
var attentionStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(24).setBold(true).build();

var lastWeightRowNum = sheet.getLastRow();  // 
var row = sheet.getRange(lastWeightRowNum-1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
row.setTextStyle(normalStyle);
row = sheet.getRange(lastWeightRowNum, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
row.setTextStyle(attentionStyle);

//Move the cursor/scroll try again at the end
var firstEmptyCellString =  `A${lastWeightRowNum+1}`;
sheet.getRange(firstEmptyCellString).activate();
};
```

The problem is the line:

```
sheet.getRange(lastWeightRow+1,1).activate();
```

and/or

```
sheet.getRange(firstEmptyCellString).activate();
```

Neither of above statement move the cursor. Somehow I am unable to move the cursor in the onEdit function whilst in the onOpen function either statement works fine. Why not in the onEdit?

Note: in order to verify that the onEdit function is really called I toggle between

```
var attentionStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(24).setBold(true).build();
```

and

```
var attentionStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(48).setBold(true).build();
```

which works as expected and the last row is 'highlighted' either with size 24 or 48.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Cursor ends up at the LastRow + 1 for me

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'DaSheet') {
    //e.source.toast('Flag1')
    var lr = sh.getLastRow();
    var normalStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(10).setBold(false).build();
    var attentionStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(24).setBold(true).build();
    sh.getRange(lr - 1, 1, 1, sh.getMaxColumns()).setTextStyle(normalStyle);
    sh.getRange(lr, 1, 1, sh.getMaxColumns()).setTextStyle(attentionStyle);
    sh.getRange(`A${lr + 1}`).activate();
  }
}
```